# How to use multiple configuration files in webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I'm building a webpack automated workflow. I completed the development server. All of my development configurations are in `webpack.config.js` file.

Then, I add it into `package.json` script via `'dev':'webpack-dev-server'`

How would one make a configuration for production in a separate file?

Comment: But what's the real advantage to have so many webpack configs?

Answer (score 26):

There are some ways to accomplish that.
Perhaps the simplest one is specifying the config file to use.
Read more about webpack [usage with config file](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#usage-with-config-file).

Add another script in your `package.json` with:

```
"build": "webpack --config ./path-to/webpack.config.prod.js"
```

Place your production config object inside `webpack.config.prod.js`.

---

Another way is using the `npm` [lifecycle event](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#current-lifecycle-event).
Update your current `webpack.config.js` script to check the target script and decide which config to use:

```js
const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
if (TARGET === 'dev') {
   module.exports = require('./path-to/webpack.config.dev.js');
}
if (TARGET === 'build') {
   module.exports = require('./path-to/webpack.config.prod.js');
}
```

You can find previous approach in this [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project on GitHub.

Comment: If the files have commonalities, how would one include the commonalities (_i.e._ a `webpack.config.core.js`)?

Comment: You might extract those commonalities into a third config file as you mentioned (e.g.: `webpack.common.js`). That script is then referenced and its config is extended with the environment specific parts. Hint: [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) is commonly used for this task. 
Hope this comment answers part of your question. If not, feel free to create a question with more information and give me a reference to check it out.

Comment: But what's the real advantage to have so many webpack configs?

Answer (score 8):

The npm module [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) is a confortable way of having multiple configuration files in webpack. It allows to have a common configuration file and several other that "extend" from this one as the following example will show.

**Installing**

`npm install webpack-merge`

**Common webpack config file**

This would be where the common configurations between your other files are.

*webpack.common.js*

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Output Management",
      template: "src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
};
```

**Extending files**

I decided to use development and production configuration files for the example but any amount can be used.

*webpack.dev.js*

```js
const path = require("path");

const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
  },
});
```

*webpack.prod.js*

```js
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
});
```

In both you import the **merge** function and use it to create your files without having to duplicate code. In your scripts you can simply call the extending configuration files like so.

*package.json*

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
  "dev": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js"
},
...
```

Comment: But what's the real advantage to have so many webpack configs?

Comment: @Rainning It depends on the complexity of the app you are building. A dev build usually is bigger and heavier but it has better error support and warnings while a production environment is the other way around.

You can't have both things the same time

Answer (score 6):

A few options:

1. use [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge)
2. use [multiple configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations) and choose between them using the [--config-name option](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#configuration-options)
3. If you don't mind changing your webpack config object (module.exports) into a function as described [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/) you could do something like this in your webpack.config.js:

   ```
   module.exports = (env, argv) => {
        return {
           //your config here, do something with the mode
              mode: env.mode
           };
       };
   ```

and pass the mode into your config by invoking webpack with the --env flag:

```
npx webpack --env mode=development
```

Or just add it to your package.json like this:

```
  "scripts": {
      "watch": "webpack --watch --env mode=development",
      "build": "webpack --env mode=production"
    }
```

Although if all you want is to toggle the mode you could just use the [--mode](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#flags) flag

Comment: But what's the real advantage to have so many webpack configs?

Answer (score 2):

In [watch mode](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-watch-mode) you can run webpack with NODE_ENV prefix from **package.json**,
for example:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    ...
  }
}
```

and then use that preset (*process.env.NODE_ENV*) in **webpack.config.js**:

```
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const config = {
  mode,
  // ... common configuration
};

if (mode === 'development') {
  // update config object for development
} else if (mode === 'production') {
  // update config object for production
}

module.exports = config;
```